# Does a normal number contain each sequence of digits infinitely often?

Tags: number-theory

I've read about [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) and wonder if each normal number contains each sequence of digits infinitely often. I think the answer is rather straightforward, isn't it, and maybe too obvious to be stated explicitely:

> If a normal number contains the sequence $d_1d_2\dots d_k$ it also
>   contains every sequence $d_1d_2\dots d_k\dots d_n$ of which there are infinitely many, thus it contains
>   $d_1d_2\dots d_k$ infinitely often.

Answer (score 2):

The **definition of "normal"** (in base 10) is that the decimal expansion of the number must contain copies of the sequence $d_1\ldots d_k$ with *limiting density* $10^{-k}$. If there were only finitely many copies, the limiting density would be $0$, so the number would not be normal.

Comment: So this is the "official" proof of the fact, that a normal number contains each sequence of digits infinitely often?

Comment: The fact is obvious. It doesn't need a proof. Still, if someone asks you for a proof for teaching purposes or something, then yes, this will do.